# Font-Awesome inconsistently rendering in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, font-face, font-awesome

I desperately want to use font-awesome for my icons in my Bootstrap project. However, rendering correctly (back to IE7) is critical for development. Support for IE7 is indicated through the use of the hack js script they offer and there is supposed support for newer versions (obviously 9 and higher are not an issue.)

I first thought the problem I'm having was only my site, and therefore thought there was an issue with my site. I've since discovered I'm wrong.

FontAwesome's own site has problems rendering on IE8 (the icons, that is) -- I haven't even bothered testing IE7.

The problem is inconsistent. Sometimes the icons show up, sometimes just the boxes that appear instead. The latter is far more common. Nine times out of 10 the icons will not render. I have to refresh the page over and over and over to eventually see the icons they way they are supposed to be seen (even then, it is not a cache issue or anything of the like, since reloading the page after that will cause it to immediately fail again!)

My question is: is Font Awesome **truly** IE7/IE8 compatible, is the problem with my browser, or am I missing something else? I need to decide if I should give up my efforts for this to work.

Comment: Here's the solution I've found which completely fixes this issue for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/33162245/4387229

Answer (score 2):

I just started having this issue today after using Font Awesome for awhile with no problems. Today also happens to be the very first time I tried version 4.0. This version released in Jun so it's possible this is the version you were experiencing this problem.

I rolled back to 3.x and now there is no issue for me. If you go to the FA website, they're using 4.0 in production and using IE8 breaks their entire site and everything turns to garbage. No icons at all.

Here's another post that is related and has some fixes. I just rolled back and will wait until they fix it on FA's end, but if you want to try some different things: [IE8 CSS @font-face fonts only working for :before content on over and sometimes on refresh/hard refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809351/ie8-css-font-face-fonts-only-working-for-before-content-on-over-and-sometimes)

Comment: The DOM ready script answer on your link fixed my issue. Thanks!