# Howto check if images have loaded using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, loading, portability

In the `OnLoad` handler of my webpage I'm trying to check if all images have loaded correctly.

I'm iterating over all `<img>` tags and check them with my `isImageLoaded()` function. Unfortunately my function only works with Firefox and IE up to version 8.

Any suggestions how I can get it to work in IE 9 and 10?

```
function isImageLoaded(img) {
    // check for IE
    if (!img.complete) {
        return false;
    }
    // check for Firefox
    if (typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // assume it's ok
    return true;
}
```

**Update:** It turns out the main culprit is that OnLoad can be fired before all image are loaded by IE9+. What would be a better trigger to check the images in the page ? I would prefer to check them all at once and not with individual OnLoad / OnError handlers.

Comment: Thanks sdespont! I'my trying to avoid using a library to keep page size down.

Comment: Did you try simply adding an `onload` event handler for each image and counting how many times they fire?

Comment: I'm currently using the page OnLoad handler. I would assume thats only called once. Do you think IE 9 + 10 call it before the images are fully loaded ?

Comment: well you can add an onload event on each image. when the event fires you can just increment a variable, lets say `imagesLoaded`. when `imagesLoaded` is the same as the amount of images on the page, all the images have been loaded.

Comment: Try `image.onload`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if an image has loaded, using Javascript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the OnLoad handler of my webpage I'm trying to check if all images have loaded correctly.

I'm assuming you are using `body.onload` or `<body onload="">`? This should still mean that all images are all loaded — however, by using:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  /// everything in the page has loaded now
});
```

Or for older versions of IE:

```
window.attachEvent('onload', function(){
  /// everything in the page has loaded now
});
```

You'll get a more consistent behaviour across browsers, and I know for a fact that `window.onload` will only trigger once everthing has loaded (that includes all other resources like javascript and css however). This link could be interesting:

[window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload)

So the above should make your function a little redundent, unless you are injecting images into the page after the `onload` event has fired. If however, you wanted to speed things up and not have to wait for *everything* to download you could use a dom ready listener and then implement the method mentioned by kennypu:

[Cross Browser Dom Ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902280/cross-browser-dom-ready)

Just as an added note, as far as I'm aware, `image.complete` should work for all modern browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement

Comment: I was indeed using window.onload and switching to window.addEventListener made things slightly better, but still fails sometimes. This makes me believe this is indeed a timing isue when the OnLoad hander is called and IE 9 and 10 seem to call it too early...

Comment: @GeneVincent if you post more of your code the StackOverflow community could help you debug exactly what is going on -- specifically your `onload` handler, but the more information the better.